# Config settings in MySQL so that it saves data on disk monthwise/yearwise

Tags: mysql, configuration

I have billions of rows in my MySQL table. So when I do a `select` for a specific date range , it takes minutes to return results, or sometimes even hangs up.

Is there any config settings in MySQL so that it saves data on disk monthwise/yearwise?

I know that MySQL saves table data in disk in `table.myd` file. I am looking for some config changes in MySQL by which we have multiple `myd` files for the same table for each month/year.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **MySQL Partitioning**.
You can partition your data on the basis of month/year.

**Example**: I have a table which I have partitioned by year

```
CREATE TABLE `RTestAll` (
  `recordDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `networkId` bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `publisherId` bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `feedId` bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subPublisherId` bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subId` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `searches` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matches` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`recordDate`,`networkId`,`publisherId`,`feedId`,`subPublisherId`,`subId`),
  KEY `K_networkId` (`networkId`),
  KEY `K_publisherId` (`publisherId`),
  KEY `K_feedId` (`feedId`),
  KEY `K_subPublisherId` (`subPublisherId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=latin1
 PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(recordDate))
(
 PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2011) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2012) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2013) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2014) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2015) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2016) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (2018) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB
) ;
```

For reference please have a look at [Partitioning Types in MySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html)

For use of partitioning, your `SELECT` queries should be designed in such a way that they use the partition key.

Going ahead please also have a look at [Limitations of partitioning.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations.html)